# I have an assigment where that I must describe some Python code, but it doesn't do anything. What should I be looking at?

Tags: python-3.6

I have an assigment where I have to describe what this bit of code does but when I type it does not do anything.  Any ideas? Here the code.

```
def unknown(word):
  for i in range(1,len(word)+1):
    if i==len(word):
      return word
    if word[i]<word[i-1]:
      word=word[:i-1]+word[i]+word[i-1]+word[i+1]
      return unknown(word)
unknown('qwerty')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing something.  You just aren't seeing what it's doing because you aren't doing anything with the output of unknown.  Try replacing

```
unknown('qwerty')
```

with

```
print(unknown('qwerty'))
```

and see what you get.

Edit:
It looks like there's a typo in your question:

```
word=word[:i-1]+word[i]+word[i-1]+word[i+1]
```

should very likely be:

```
word=word[:i-1]+word[i]+word[i-1]+word[i+1:]
```

That change should make it do a recursive bubble sort.